# Simple javascript change image not working

Tags: javascript, css

I want to change an image's src on click of a link. I got a javascript snippet and tried to integrate it but it doesn't work.Im

Here's my HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<script src="styles/script.js"></script>
  <img id="bgimage" src="images/1.jpg"/>

  <nav id="nav"><a href="" onclick="changeImage()">A</a> | B |
  </nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is my script.js:

```
var imageId = document.getElementById("bgimage");
    function changeImage() {

        if (imageId.src == "images/1.jpg") 
        {
            imageId.setAttribute("src","images/2.jpg");
        }
        else 
        {
            imageId.setAttribute("Src","images/1.jpg");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Any reason your not using jquery? I would make my answer a lot cleaner.

Comment: im just learning html and css, this is for my project and we're not allowed to use other language..

Comment: just checked the console and my imageId is null, how come?

Comment: Jquery is a javascript package. But I guess that falls into a grey area if this is for a project.

Answer (score 1):

You must place your script just before `</body>`, or run it at `onload`.

If not, you run

```
var imageId = document.getElementById("bgimage");
```

before loading the image to the DOM, so `imageId` is `null`.

---

Anyway, you could improve your function to

```
var images = ["images/1.jpg", "images/2.jpg" /*, ... */];
function changeImage() {
    imageId.src = images[(images.indexOf(imageId.src)+1) % images.length];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is occurring because the script appears in the html before the `<img`> element. Therefore, the code tries to find the img element, but it can't because the js code executes before the rest of the html is parsed. Correct it by putting the js include tag just before `</body>`:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
  <img id="bgimage" src="images/1.jpg"/>

  <nav id="nav"><a href="" onclick="changeImage()">A</a> | B |
  </nav>

<script src="styles/script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Or, you might want to use `DOMContentLoaded` to wait until the html has been parsed. Change the js to this, in that case:

```
var changeImage;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(){
var imageId = document.getElementById("bgimage");
changeImage=function() {

    if (imageId.src == "images/1.jpg") 
    {
        imageId.setAttribute("src","images/2.jpg");
    }
    else 
    {
        imageId.setAttribute("Src","images/1.jpg");
    }
}
},false);
```

Or you could call `document.getElementById()` every time `changeImage` is called